# Random composite integer n with 200 digits and Miller-Rabin witnesses

Tags: random, number-theory

I wanna take a random composite integer n with 200 digits and check how many, out of 100 random integers, that are Miller-Rabin witnesses for compositeness of the integer n.

The first thing I need to do is to generate the composite composite integer n with 200 digits:
Since all non-primes are compsoite integers, I tried something as follow:

```
A = 0
While[A != prime, n = RandomPrime[{10^199, 10^200}], 100]
```

Then I check the Miller-Rabin witnesses for compositeness of the integer n using:

```
PrimeQ[n]
```

This implementation is not perfect, so I need some help. Any suggestion?

Comment: To generate a composite integer with 200 digits, you can do `R := Module[{s}, While[PrimeQ[s = RandomInteger[{10^199, 10^200 - 1}]]]; s]` and then every call to `R` will give you such a number. For example, `Table[R, 100]` will generate 100 composite integers with 200 characters each.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Is it correct that I can check the Miller-Rabin witnesses for compositeness of the integer n using $PrimeQ[n]$ or should I do it differently?

Comment: `PrimeQ` will return `False` on any composite number (it's stronger than Miller-Rabin). You'll have to implement Miller-Rabin yourself.

Comment: OK, but if the Miller-rabin test says "False", then I'm done. Right?

Comment: What is `prime`? Why would we ever obtain `A==prime`? Why would a number produced by `RandomPrime` ever fail a Miller-Rabin test?

Answer (score 2):

The book [here](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000RGUPQ6) provides Mathematica code for the Miller-Rabin test.
The code below is slightly improved to include new features in Mathematica.

```
SpspSequence[b_,n_]:=With[{s=IntegerExponent[n-1,2]},
  NestList[Mod[#^2,n]&,PowerMod[b,(n-1)/2^s,n],s]/.n-1->-1];

StrongPseudoprimeQ[b_,n_]:=With[{bSeq=DeleteDuplicates[SpspSequence[b,n]]},
  bSeq=={1}||Min[bSeq]==-1
];

MillerRabinTest[n_,numberBases_,{minBase_,maxBase_}]/;
  Element[{n,numberBases,minBase,maxBase},PositiveIntegers]:=
    And@@Map[StrongPseudoprimeQ[#,n]&,RandomPrime[{minBase,maxBase},numberBases]]
```

Then the following returns numbers that pass the Miller-Rabin test using 5 prime bases.

```
Select[Range[100, 150], MillerRabinTest[#, 5, {2, 50}] &]
(*{101,103,107,109,113,127,131,137,139,149}*)
```